# Object 'user' has no atribute 'create' - Django

Tags: python, django, synapsepay

I have a question about an error that I am getting. I have a query that I am trying to send based on the Synapse Api for my project. I am currently trying to senda request taht creates a new user with the API. Every time I try to to send the request, I get a message that the User object doesnt have a create. Here is the error.

```
AttributeError at /setup_profile/
type object 'User' has no attribute 'create'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/setup_profile/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
type object 'User' has no attribute 'create'
Exception Location: C:\Users\OmarJandali\Desktop\opentab\opentab\tab\views.py in createUserSynapse, line 1104
```

Here is the current code that I have which will create the request to create a new user.

```
def createUserSynapse(request):
    args = {
        'email': 'hello@synapsepay.com',
        'phone_number': '555-555-5555',
        'legal_name': 'Hello McHello',
        'note': ':)',  # optional
        'supp_id': '123abc',  # optional
        'is_business': True,
        'cip_tag': 1
    }

    user = User.create(client, **args)
    print(user)
```

Now i do know that with a normal query set, I have the object in the following format

```
User.objects.create(client, **args)
```

but when i do that I get an error that says

two parameters are being passed and 1 is requires so I think there is to many variables being passed... I am not sure where the error is coming from...

here is the error that I get when I use the User.objects.create(client, ** args)

```
TypeError at /setup_profile/
create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/setup_profile/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception Location: C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py in manager_method, line 127
```

**UPDATED**

The client needs to be passed into the api call and it contains the following:

```
import os
from synapse_pay_rest import Client

args = {
    'client_id': 'client_id_...6YiBl',
    'client_secret': 'client_secret_...kC3IF',
    'fingerprint': '...dd48b',
    'ip_address': '127.0.0.1',
    'development_mode':True,
    'logging':False
}

client = Client(**args)
```

Also, here is a github link to the api samples that were created by the api developers.

https://github.com/synapsepay/SynapsePayRest-Python

the client has to be passed with the api call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create method has only key word arguments. Rewrite your code to this:

```
User.objects.create(client=client, **args)
```

**UPDATE**

I just figured out that you are using third party package. So you need to import User class like this `from synapse_pay_rest import User as SynapseUser` and use SynapseUser in your code: `SynapseUser.create(clients, **argss)`

Comment: I tried that it did not work. I got the following message... `TypeError at /setup_profile/
'client' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/setup_profile/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
'client' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. pleaase look at my update and link to the api that i am using.. @neverwalkaloner

Comment: @OmarJandali you dont need to pass client to create user. Tru just this: User.objects.create(**args)

Comment: the thing is i am not creating a local user, I am trying to pass the args to the api and to do that i need to send a request through the client with the client's header arguments.... I just am not sure how to do that... @neverwalkaloner

Comment: @OmarJandali are you sure you are import correct user class: `from synapse_pay_rest import User` instead build-in django User?

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure it is different User than the build in django user.. How can I import User and assign it a different name to use... @neverwalkaloner

Comment: You got it, I had to change the name of the module that i imported and it worked....

Comment: Thank you so much... you helped with a problem that I have been having for 5 days now and it was as simple as that.

Comment: @OmarJandali glad this helped:)

Comment: I really appreciate the help. again. I have checked it as a working solution @neverwalkaloner